# sailsjs error view stopped being rendered as HTML pages with layout and is now mere text

Tags: sails.js

I am using **sails v0.10.0-rc8**

For some reason, res.serverError stopped rendering the 404/500.ejs files found in views folder, it only renders text files!!!

Note that according to my source control there are no changes that might affect it.

For example:

```
return res.serverError("Invalid input") // renders an html page with the content "Invalid input".
```

What might be wrong or how do I the problem?

I have no clue where are the config of error routings.

Comment: What version of sails.js are you using?

Comment: sorry, updated my question (v0.10.0-rc8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As displayed on the `api/responses/serverError.js` file, the usage for the function is as follows:

```
/**
 * 500 (Server Error) Response
 *
 * Usage:
 * return res.serverError();
 * return res.serverError(err);
 * return res.serverError(err, 'some/specific/error/view');
 *
 * NOTE:
 * If something throws in a policy or controller, or an internal
 * error is encountered, Sails will call `res.serverError()`
 * automatically.
 */
```

If you look at the code, however, if no second argument is supplied, it will try to do `res.view('500', { data: data })`. Make sure that your `500.ejs` file is correctly located in the `views/` folder.. it might be helpful to insert a console.log() in the callback for the `res.view('500')` function to see if there was an error rendering that template.

Comment: @user2867106 it's not really clear to the rest of this *how* this solved your problem.  Was your **500.ejs** file missing?  Did it contain errors?